# Using checkbox to display or hide button in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, two-way-binding

I am trying to display or hide buttons based on the checkbox. Following is my HTML code :

```
<input class="form-check-input" [(ngModel)]="switchCase" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" (change)="toggleButton()"
<button class="btn btn-primary"  *ngIf="!switchCase" [disabled]="!userform.valid">Button A</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary"  *ngIf="switchCase" [disabled]="!userform.valid">Button B</button>
```

Following is my TS code :

```
    toggleButton(){
        console.log("Before : "+this.switchCase);
        this.switchCase = !this.switchCase;
        console.log("After : "+this.switchCase);
    }
```

The value of `switchCase` changes according to the checkbox value and logs correctly in the console. However, the buttons do not toggle accordingly and I can only see Button A. I am new to angular and not sure where I am going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.html Code

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked"
                                (change)="toggleButton()">
<button class="btn btn-primary" *ngIf="!switchCase">Button
                                A</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" *ngIf="switchCase">Button
                                B</button>
```

.ts code

```
public switchCase: boolean = false;
  toggleButton() {
    this.switchCase = !this.switchCase;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But can you tell me what was I doing wrong ?

Comment: [(ngModel)]="switchCase" is two way binding so you don't need to use `ngModel`